# Page redirects to archive

Tags: pages, redirect, archives

I have a page with a permalink of /news and when i go to that page it redirects me to archive pages.

I only want to go my news page and not redirect me to archive.

Please help.. thanks

Comment: Hi, when does this happen? Always? Can you access your page by clicking the `view` button in the pages list in back-end?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the same slug "news" for custom post type and page. If it is the case, I would like to recommend to change the slug for custom post type to something like "cpt_news" or anyone that you think is best.